# How to use akka-http-circe on client side calls?

Tags: scala, unmarshalling, akka-http, circe

I'm trying to do a simple REST API call using akka-http, circe and [akka-http-json](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json) (akka-http-circe in particular).

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._

object Blah extends FailFastCirceSupport {
   //...
   val fut: Future[Json] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri))
```

I'm expecting `akka-http-circe` to figure out how to unmarshal a `HttpResponse` to my wanted type (here, just `Json`). But it doesn't compile.

So I looked at some documentation and samples around, and tried this:

```
val fut: Future[Json] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri)).flatMap(Unmarshal(_).to)
```

Gives: `type mismatch; found 'Future[HttpResponse]', required 'Future[Json]'`. How should I expose an unmarshaller for the fetch?

*Scala 2.12.4, akka-http 10.0.10, akka-http-circe 1.18.0*

Answer (score 2):

The working code seems to be:

```
val fut: Future[Json] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri)).flatMap(Unmarshal(_).to[Json])
```

When the target type is explicitly given, the compiler finds the necessary unmarshallers and this works. It works equally with a custom type in place of `Json`.

Further question: Is this the best way to do it?